# Simulation is Stuck in Selectoutput block

Tags: anylogic

Please refer to the simulation that I have created. I need to Combine Output of Machine 1 and Machine 2 and Transfer it to Machine 3 and machine 4.
I used Selectoutput with 0.5 probability for both machines M1 and M2 (such that half of each machine output will be divided).
After that I combined the output with Combineobject 1 and CombineObject 2.

But even though machines ahead are free (machine 3 & machine 4) my simulation is stuck at select output.

is there something I am missing? I checked all the capacities , they are OK.

Any Help would be appreciated. (I am using the free version of anylogic).

[image: SimulationScreenShot]

Thanks,
Vinayak

Comment: It is not in the Selectoutput block, no agent is ever in those. Likely, your combine blocks are setup wrong, blocking the upstream flow. Care to share their setup?

Comment: Hello benjamin! I used a different approach to model. I used "Select output in and Select output out".
thanks,
Vinayak